# firebase MQTT actions

Tags: node.js, mqtt, actions-on-google

I am building google action with dialogflow. I also deployed nodejs fulfillment in firebase. Inoder to connect to the IoT devices which are connected to google homes, I am using MQTT protocol, VerneMQ is the broker which I am using. I executed the code in local machine and I was able to subscribe to the message the publish by the google home. But when i upload this code to firebase, I was not able to establish the connection. As their are limitation to debug firebase, I put logs and i find that the device is not connected to MQTT broker.  What should I do to connect? Is firebase support MQTT connection?

Comment: What does "nodejs fulfillment in firebase" mean?  If you are using Cloud Functions for Firebase they are a serverless product that only runs in response to events like database changes and HTTP requests.  If you try to establish a connection from a Firebase function to another service it won't work outside the context of a database event or HTTP request

Comment: Thank you for responding. I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading my firebase account from 'spark' to 'Blaze' as the spark plan dosen't support outbound services.